# Tsung SOAP call

Tags: soap, asp.net-web-api, tsung

I'm trying to test the performance of the web service via SOAP calls using Tsung.
I've wrote the script like it's described in this example: http://lists.process-one.net/pipermail/tsung-users/2010-November/001584.html

```
<request>
<http url="/Service.asmx" version="1.0" contents_from_file="/home/local/user/.tsung/c.xml" content_type="application/soap+xml; charset=UTF-8"  method="POST">     
<soap action="Retrieve"/>
</http>
</request>
```

I've checked contents_from_file="" and contents="" work similar so it doesn't cause the issue.

The issue is that I don't receive any answer from the server. The dump file looks like this:

```
NewClient:1421147358.215102:1
load:1
Send:1421147358.22721:<0.94.0>:POST /Service.asmx HTTP/1.0
Host: webservice.com
User-Agent: tsung
SOAPAction: "Retrieve"
Content-Type: application/soap+xml; charset=UTF-8
Content-Length: 1991

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
<SOAP-ENV:Header>
    <!-- headers -->
</SOAP-ENV:Header>
<SOAP-ENV:Body>
    <!-- body -->
</SOAP-ENV:Body>
</SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
```

And then - nothing. And there are no errors in the tsung_controller@.log

The same request was already created by previous qa engineer in the Parasoft Load Test tool and it works. I'm trying to reproduce it with Tsung.

What am I doing wrong? Could someone help me with this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolved.
I've had an error in the config file. 
I've used incorrect `port` and `type` values in the `servers` tag.
Such requests work fine.